# Client-Server framework for python

Tags: python, frameworks, client-server

I'm currently working on a University project that needs to be implemented with a Client - Server model.
I had experiences in the past where I was managing the communication at socket level and that really sucked.
I was wondering if someone could suggest an easy to use python framework that I can use for that purpose.
I don't know what kind of details you may need to answer so I'm just going to describe the project briefly.

- Communication should happen over HTTP, possibly HTTPS.
- The server does not need to send data back or invoke methods on the clients, it just collects data
- Many clients send data concurrently to server, who needs to distinguish the sender, process the data accordingly and put the result in a database.

Comment: What network protocol are you supposed to user? Can you use HTTP?

Comment: I should use HTTPS but the demo will not cover that part of the project, it can be HTTP then

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like Flask or Django.  Both frameworks are fairly easy to implement, Flask is much easier than Django IMO, although Django has a built in authentication layer that you can use, albeit more difficult to implement in a client/server scenario like you need.

I would personally use Flask and JWT (JSON Web Tokens), which will allow you to give a token to each client for authentication with the server, which will also let you differentiate between clients, and you can use HTTPS for your SSL/TLS requirement.  It is tons easier to implement this, and although I like django better for what it brings to the table, it is probably overkill to have you learn it for a single assignment.

For Flask with SSL, [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/) is a quick rundown of that.

For JWT with Flask, [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/) is that.

You can use any database system you would like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can use any web framework in python. For instance, you can use Flask (I use it and I like it). Django is also a popular choice among the python web frameworks. However, you shouldn't be limited to only these two. There are plenty of them out there. Just google for them.

The implementation of the client depends on what kind of communication there will be between the clients and the server - I don't have enough details here. I only know it's unidirectional.

The client can be a browser accessing you web application written in Flask where users send only POST requests to the server. However, even here the communication will bidirectional (the clients need to open the page which means the server sends requests back to the client) and it violates your initial requirement.

Then it can be a specific client written in python sending some particular requests to your server over http/https. For instance, your client can use a `requests` package to send HTTP requests.

Comment: I was not clear with my statement. I didn't mean that the server could not send messages to the clients, I meant that the server does not NEED to send data to the clients. I'm going to edit my post. Thank you for your suggestions, I'll check Flask and Django out!

Comment: I took a look to Flask and it appears to be meant for web applications. I actually need a small python program (client) that sends data taken from a .txt to another python program (server).

Comment: @Dr. Frank Fox, I would still use flask and run it on WSGI compatible application server because it will handle multiple concurrent requests for you if you have several clients. Then you can write a small client in python. As I have already told you can use `requests` package for sending http requests to your server.